# How to download a file using the signed URL of google cloud storage in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have returned the signed url for a file in the GCP as a response , now I want to use it to download this file through my angular frontend. I have tried appending an anchor tag dynamically but instead of downloading it only displays the file. Anyone knows a solution for this? This is how it currently looks like. Thanks in advance !
[image]

Comment: Please do post any code snippets as text so its easier for us to copy and modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`responseDisposition`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/storage/getsignedurlconfig#_google_cloud_storage_GetSignedUrlConfig_responseType_member) property in [`GetSignedUrlConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/storage/getsignedurlconfig) to [`attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#:%7E:text=or%20as%20an-,attachment,-%2C%20that%20is%20downloaded) as shown below:

```
const [url] = await storage
  .bucket("[bucket]")
  .file("[path]")
  .getSignedUrl({
    version: "v4",
    action: "read",
    responseDisposition: "attachment", 
    // optionally specify file name
    // responseDisposition: "attachment; filename=name.ext",
    expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000,
  });

return url;
```

Then redirect use to the URL after getting the signed URL like this:

```
window.open(this.downloadUrl, '_blank').focus();
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much for the clear answer, could not expect any better!